# $P[(X_1,...,X_n)\in B]=P[(c_1X_1,...,c_nX_n)\in B]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_1,...,X_n)$ be an independent $n$-tuple of real random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ so that $X_i$ has the same distribution as $-X_i$.  Furthermore let $B\in\mathscr B(\mathbb R^n)$ and $c_1,...,c_n\in\{-1,1\}$.
Show that $P[(X_1,...,X_n)\in B]=P[(c_1X_1,...,c_nX_n)\in B]$.
I don't know how to start here, does anyone have a hint?

Comment: The claim is false. Let $n=1$, $X_1\sim\textrm{Ber}(p)$, $c_1=-1$. Let $B=\{1\}$. Then $P(X_1\in B)=P(X_1=1)=p$ but $P(c_1X_1\in B)=P(X_1=-1)=0$.

Comment: If $B$ is not somehow symmetric then there is no way to expect this to be true.

Comment: " [...] so that $X_i$ has the same distribution as $X_i$ " - this doesn't seem like a good assumption. You probably meant " [...] so that $X_i$ has the same distribution as $- X_i$ ", right? Then, the claim is at least correct.

Comment: @DominikKutek yes, I mean $X_i$ has the same distribution as $-X_i$

Comment: Since $c_i\in \{-1, 1\}$ and $X_i$ are symmetry and independent, it follows that the law of ${\bf X}'=(c_1X_1,\ldots, c_nX_n)$ is the same as ${\bf X}=(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and hence the result. To see why the ${\bf X}'$ and ${\bf X}$ have the same law, take a cylinder set $B=\prod A_i$ and note that $P((c_1X_1, \ldots, c_nX_n)\in B)=\prod_i P(c_iX_i\in A_i)=\prod_iP(X_i\in A_i)$. Extending it from cylinder set to product of Borel sigma algebra is `usual nonsense'.